# Weird register hex value 0x010000edu in QEMU edu PCI device

Tags: c, hex, variable-assignment, qemu, pci

In the [sourcecode](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.7.0/hw/misc/edu.c#L182) for the QEMU edu PCI device, written in C, the following assignment is made:

```
val = 0x010000edu;
```

(also stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/v2.7.0/docs/specs/edu.txt#L41)).

This should be the value stored in the internal register of the device with offset `0x00` (the first one). `u` is not a hex value. Actually reading the contents of the register from an OS, only `0x010000ed` is shown.

The above assignment `val = 0x010000edu` seems meaningless. Why, then, it has been made this way?

---

In a test program, I can make:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <inttypes.h>

void main() {
uint32_t testvalue = 0x010000edu;
printf("%08x\n", testvalue);
}
```

It successfully compiles and `001000ed` is printed on screen. But:

```
uint32_t testvalue = 0x010u00ed;
```

would provoke a compiler error:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:9:19: error: invalid suffix "u00ed" on integer constant
    9 |  uint32_t testvalue = 0x010u00ed;
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

What I can not understand is why the `u` is not rejected in both cases,  because it is not a `hex` digit.

Comment: I do not understand. Are you confused by the `u` suffix only? Or are you asking what is the meaning of `0x010000ed` value?  `seems meaningless.` Why? It assigns `0x010000ed` to variable `val`, seems like it's doing something that has meaning.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am confused by the presence of a `u` on a hex expression. `u` is not a hex digit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *integer constant* in C language can have a *suffix*, that determines/changes the type of the integer literal. See [cppreference integer constant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant).

Suffix `u` or `U` with an hexadecimal integer constant is used to change the type of the literal to `unsigned int` `unsigned long int` or `unsigned long long int`. The suffix `u` is used when you want to specify the type of literal to be unsigned, in this case `0x010000ed` could be an `int` or `long` depending on architecture, that would undergo signed to unsigned conversion when assigning to `uint32_t` variable. Or [someone has to follow rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/c/RSPEC-854), or it could serve as an documentation that the value is unsigned.

@edit it's "integer constant" in C, "literal" in C++

Comment: Ok! A couple of doubts: 1) In my example C program, being `testvalue` *declared* as unsigned, with no specific style obligations, it is *possible* to use the trailing u, but *it is not necessary*. Is this right? 2) In my case, `testvalue` is not a constant. But maybe with *integer constant* you mean any fixed values, even those assigned to a *variable*.

Comment: 1) Well, it's always possible to add a suffix to integer constant It's a programmers decision. Because the constant is used in assigment, yes, I don't see a need to add a `u` suffix here. Personally, I think it's a good style. 2) No? By the term _integer constant_ I mean what C standard defines as [integer constant](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1) - a hexadecimal prefix `0x` followed by `[0-9a-fA-F]+` optionally followed by a suffix.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help and patience.